# the function doSomethingWithData(v) is being called with the wrong value of the variable V. T

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
    const Hello = () => {
      const [v, setV] = React.useState(1);
    
      React.useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(async () => {
          await setV(2);
          doSomethingWithData(v)
        }, 3000)
      }, []);
    
    
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>Hello, world {v}!</h1>
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    const doSomethingWithData = (v) => {
      //report e-commerce data to our server here..
      
    console.log('Variable value is: ' + v);
    }
    
    ReactDOM.render(
      <Hello />,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

the function `doSomethingWithData(v)` is being called with the wrong value of the variable `V`. That is problematic because a record will be created in our e-commerce database when `doSomethingWithData()` is called and as a result we might make choices based on faulty data.can someone explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following does not work as you expect. `setV` is async but it does not return a promise to wait for.

```
async () => {
    await setV(2);
    doSomethingWithData(v);
};
```

The general pattern is to use `useEffect` hook with a dependency value which is `v` in your case.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        setV(2);
    }, 3000);
}, []);

React.useEffect(() => {
    doSomethingWithData(v);
}, [v]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the data available just pass that to doSomethingWithData.

```
    React.useEffect(() => {
      setV(2);
      doSomethingWithData(2)
  }, []);
```

The view will display the data from the state v and doSomethingWithData won't be a state behind.